# Is there a service that tags songs based on the subject matter of the lyrics?

Tags: lyrics, genre

Today we are improving tagging a song/album/artist a lot with music streaming applications where music search is pivotal. I'm looking for a certain type of music which concerns the lyrics, so I'm wondering - is there an online service where I can list songs where they sing about a certain subject?

In some cases I know that there are genres like, for instance Christian music, Love songs, Gospel. But what about more niche lyrics such as Gambling, Zombies, Computer gaming, Vikings etc.

With Spotify, I can find a song where they sing about Superman, if I try to find similar songs or related artists I will find songs that sounds the same, but not many songs about Superman, Spriderman or any other super hero.

This questions is not only about software features, which is why I decided to ask it in the music QA. I'm wondering if there's a genre concept for this at all, or if I simply will need to try to find lyrics by word and then try to cherry-pick songs.

Comment: I imagine searching for terms on a lyrics database web site might get you what you are looing for.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing to stop tags being used for any category you want, but generally tags are limited to genre (eg Rock, Blues, Folk etc.) so this is unlikely to give you anything useful.

Your simplest bet may be to trawl the various online lyrics databases - some have open API's, others may just be a case of scripting a search.