# How to automatically tag music genres of songs?

Tags: genre

I want to organize my mp3 music by genre, but many of the songs are completely missing genre information. Some are incorrectly labeled as well, and some have useless variations (e.g., "Blues-rock" and "Blues Rock").

What's the best method for cleaning up a mp3 library?

One existing solution that does not seem to work anymore is the plugin/extension for MediaMonkey called [GenreFinder 5](https://www.mediamonkey.com/addons/browse/item/genre-finder). Does an equivalent solution exist?

Comment: Related https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/755/is-there-a-service-that-tags-songs-based-on-the-subject-matter-of-the-lyrics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to organize my mp3 music by genre

One alternative is MusicBrainz Picard, here are some tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02fWYIur42g

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvyArCzh-WQ

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46Kh8P7zKjc

Answer (score 1):

beets gets the genres from Last.fm, similar to GenreFinder.

You can read more about it: http://beets.io and https://beets.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.7